# How to pass credentials from nginx auth_request module to authentication server

Tags: authentication, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

i am trying to authenticate client requests with nginx ngx_http_auth_request_module module but unable to forword the authentication parameters  to authentication server

Below is the nginx configuration i am using

```
 http {
        upstream myapp {
                server localhost;
        }
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;
        server {
                listen       80;
                server_name  localhost;
                    location /{
                        auth_request     /auth;
                        location = /auth {
 internal;
                                proxy_method POST;
                                proxy_pass              "http://192.168.26.100:1985/resource";
                                proxy_pass_request_body off;
                                proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
                                proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
                                proxy_set_header Host       $http_host;
                               # proxy_set_body $auth_foo;
                                #auth_request_set $auth_foo $upstream_http_foo;
                                #proxy_set_header x-user $user;
                                #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        }
                }
        }
```

i tried default proxy_method (GET) and after that i changed it to POST but without any use , is there any way that i can pass credentials to Authentication server so that i can validate the user is autherised or not,here http://192.168.26.100:1985/resource is the Authentication server url

Thank you

Comment: what do you get in the nginx logs?

Comment: nginx is able to send subrequest to Authentication server if i send 200 in responce to nginx , content  is getting transferred to client  for responce 400 from authentication server i am getting the following error        *9 auth request unexpected status: 400 while sending to client, client: 192.168.26.100, server: localhost, request: "GET /Last.mp4 HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.26.100" ,

Comment: The auth happens using a POST? I think that may be the problem, the auth might be going as a GET request. Can you check authentication server log and see how it receives the request?

Comment: by default it is GET request only but i am implementing authentication server  to validate the client ,like this  
  
Client  ----> nginx    --------> authentication server 
  |   |
  <-------200if client is valid otherwise 401 


if i change proxy_method to POST and handling POST method in authentication server i am getting request , but my problem is how to proceed after that for validation credentials is there any other way to do this or my entire procedure is wrong ?